Cross-platform USB communication via HID device
I am trying to create a cross-platform app with .net maui. The purpose of the app is to be able to communicate with a USB device (HID) by sending and receiving raw data.
After much research I managed to find the library ‘hidlibrary’ which works perfectly on Windows form, however on .net maui at the first instruction to receive data it gives me the exception ‘Operation not supported on this platform’. How can I solve this? Am I taking the wrong approach? Thanks in advance
